# Subjecting input to multiple regex in the form of a conditional?

Tags: perl

I got great input here on subjecting a string of nucleotides to a search for a repeating pattern of 3 nucleotides with the requirement that the repeat happen 7 time consecutively by constructing regex for it.

```
my $regex1 = qr/( ([ACGT]{3}) \2{6,} )/x;
```

I understand how to expand it to search for 2 nucs in a row of 10 as well as 4 in a row of 7.

But I would like to expand the code so that a user can point to their input file and it checks for the above regex as well as the two other regex I would need to create for the other two searches.

EDIT: How do I subject my input file to multiple regexs like the one above? I've created two other regex in the code (knocked out by hash symbols)

Here is my current code

```
print "Please specify the file location (DO NOT DRAG/DROP files!) then press ENTER:\n";
$seq = <STDIN>;

#Remove the newline from the filename
chomp $seq;

#open the file or exit
open (SEQFILE, $seq) or die "Can't open '$seq': $!";

#read the dna sequence from the file and store it into the array variable @seq1
@seq1 = <SEQFILE>;

#Close the file
close SEQFILE;

#Put the sequence into a single string as it is easier to search for the motif
$seq1 = join( '', @seq1);

#Remove whitespace
$seq1 =~s/\s//g;

#Count of number of nucleotides
#Initialize the variable
$number = 0;
$number = length $seq1;

#Use regex to say "Find 3 nucelotides and match at least 6 times
# qr(quotes and compiles)/( ([nucs]{number of nucs in pattern}) \2{number of repeats,}/x(permit within pattern)
my $regex1 = qr/( ([ACGT]{3}) \2{6,} )/x;
#my $regex = qr/( ([ACGT]){2}) \2{9,} )/x;
#my $regex2 = qr/( ([ACGT]{4}) \2{6,} )/x;

#Tell program to use $regex on variable that holds the file
$seq1 =~ $regex1;

#Now print the results to screen
#This will need to change to printing to a file (WHAT KIND OF FILE?)in the following manner :site, nucelotide match, # of times, length of full sequence
printf "MATCHED %s exactly %d times\n", $2, length($1)/3;
print "Length of sequence: $number\n";
exit;
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Sorry - I wasn't clear. I want to subject my input file to multiple regexs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use a `for` loop. Something like

```
for my $regex ($regex1, $regex2, $regex3) {
  next unless $seq1 =~ $regex;
  printf "MATCHED %s exactly %d times\n", $2, length($1)/length($2);
}
```

But you will probably want to change the output to describe the results better.

Comment: I would need to change the 'length($1)/n;', but how would I go about matching the regex used to the printf it should use?

Comment: It is hard to suggest anything without knowing what output you would like. But you can change the expression to `length($1)/length($2)`. Answer changed accordingly.

Comment: Since the input seq will only meet one of the three regex requirements, I need to address the regexs that do not find anything, which return `length($2)` as `0`, which kills the program. How can I tell the program to only provide results for the regex it used?

Comment: Answer fixed for that too. Anything else? :)

Comment: Nope! I think I can get that working. You've been a great help!